# prepare file in audio recorder with swift 3 iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10

[image]

error is

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1718449215.)
>   error in prepare audio recorde

Comment: Don't post your code with images, there is a special code tag.

Comment: how can edit the original post

Comment: There is the `edit` button